# C linked list segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am new to data structure and having some trouble implementing double linked list. After taking all the input compiler showing segmentation fault (core dumped). Cannot find the mistake. 
I searched for core dump errors as well as segmentation fault but it didnt help. 
Here is my code:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *lptr,*rptr;
};

struct node *head;

void create(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *newp,*ptr;
    int num,n;

    printf("Enter the no. of elements you want to enter :\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("Enter the elements:\n");

    while(n)
    {
        scanf("%d",&num);
        n--;

        if(head==NULL)
        {
            newp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            newp->lptr=NULL;
            newp->data=num;
            newp->rptr=NULL;
            head=newp;
            printf("Head created\n");
            ptr=head;

        }

        else
        {
            while(ptr->rptr)
            {
                ptr=ptr->rptr;
            }

            ptr->rptr=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            ptr->rptr->lptr=ptr;
            ptr->data=num;
            ptr->rptr->rptr=NULL;
            ptr=ptr->rptr;
            printf("node inserted\n");
        }
    }
}   

void display(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=head;
    while(ptr->rptr)
    {
        printf("%d\t",ptr->data );
        ptr=ptr->rptr;
    }
}

void main()
{   
    head=NULL;

    create(head);
    display(head);
}
```

Comment: Note that you have multiple *different* variables named `head`. They are not connected in any way.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `create()` function modifies the `head` variable locally, so when you call `display()`, it does not point to newly created list.

Modify the create function to return new head pointer. Here is sample change. Some things you need to work out like you don't need to pass `head` parameter to it or need to return `head` only when new list created etc.

```
struct node *create(struct node *head)
{

....

   return head;
}

void main()
{   
    head=NULL;

   head = create(head);
    display(head);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In Main function you are assign NULL value to the global variable header.
Then you are passing NULL value to create function. 
You are allocating memory only to the local variable head in the create function.

Then you are passing same null value to the display function and inside display you are trying to access NULL address resulting in segmentation fault..

As a fix you have allocate memory to head in main function and send pass address of head (&head) to create and display function

```
`struct node *create(struct node **head)
 {
      ....

      return head;
  }

void main()
{   
    head=malloc(...);
    head = create(&head);
    display(&head);
}`
```

Answer (score -2):

```
void create(struct node *head){}
```

When you update `head` inside `create()` you actually update the passed copy.You need `struct node **head` and then update `*head`.
At the same time you can avoid passing `head` to `create()` since it is global.

Then

```
ptr->rptr->lptr=ptr;
ptr->data=num;
```

should be, otherwise you end up updating the previous node.

```
 ptr->rptr->lptr=ptr;
 ptr->rptr->data=num;
```

and `display()` should be, otherwise you won't print the last node.

```
while(ptr)
{
    printf("%d\t",ptr->data );
    ptr=ptr->rptr;
}
```